# How do I view BGP communities of received routes in IOS XE before they go through route-map import policy?

Tags: bgp, juniper-junos, ios-xe, cisco-ios-xr

I want to see the communities that are attached to a route when I first receive the route before it goes through the BGP import route-map. In my instance the route-map strips communities off so I cannot tell just by looking at the routes in BGP like I'd do normally. It's a live production network so I can't just modify the route-map to see it temporarily.

I've figured out how to see these in XR by looking at the received-only at the bottom of the "show bgp vrf  " command. Which is a question here [How to view BGP community attached to prefix in Cisco ASR routers?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-to-view-bgp-community-attached-to-prefix-in-cisco-asr-routers)

I've also figured out how to do it in junos with the "show route receive-protocol bgp  table .inet  detail" command.

Any guidance in IOS XE is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To display routes that belong to specified BGP communities, use the **show ip bgp community** command in EXEC mode.

> **show ip bgp community** *community-number* *[exact]*

**community-number :** Valid value is a community number in the range from 1 to 4294967200, or AA:NN (autonomous system-community number/2-byte number), internet, no-export, local-as, or no-advertise.

**exact :** (Optional) Displays only routes that have the same specified communities.

The following is sample output from the **show ip bgp community** command in privileged EXEC mode:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`show ip bgp neighbor x.x.x.x received-routes` is what you want. This will show you prefixes received from a given neighbor *before* any import policies have been applied, aka the Adj-RIB-In. However, this command will only work if you have `soft-reconfiguration inbound` configured for the neighbor.